# how do I restrict this loop to a specific number?

Tags: php

how do I restrict this loop to get only 6 values?

```
  $countries = array();
foreach ($my_data as $node)
{   
    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $href)
    {   

        $countries[] = strip_tags(trim($href->nodeValue)); 


    }
}
```

Comment: Does your getElementsByTagName('a') is a PHP function? Where did you defined it?

Comment: @Eric [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $href)
{
    if ($i++ === 6) break;   
    $countries[] = strip_tags($href->nodeValue); 

}
```

Comment: Adding a variable to count iterations inside a foreach loop is killing the purpose of having a foreach loop in my opinion... And a 'break' instruction inside a loop is probably not such a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that getElementsByTagName() returns an array.  In that case you could:

```
foreach(array_slice($node->getElementsByTagName('a'),0,6) as $href)
{   
    $countries[] = strip_tags($href->nodeValue); 

}
```

See: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: This might be a more expensive than Gentautas's solution.

Comment: @Dustin: Maybe. But don't forget that it's only for 6 elements, so the difference is probably neglictible. I think Dustin' solution is cleaner since it doesn't imply a break inside a foreach loop.

Comment: When you say "not working" what do you mean?  Are you getting more or less iterations through the loop than you expect?

Comment: Maybe you should paste your entire code so it would be easier for us to help you!

Comment: @Dustin [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), as the manual says, returns a DOMNodeList. Array functions won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter to count values and then `break` out of the loop if that counter reaches 6:

```
$countryCount = 0
foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $href)
    {   
        $countries[] = strip_tags($href->nodeValue);
        $countryCount++
        if ($countryCount >= 6) break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it...

```
$countries = array();

$countryCount = 0;
$countryLimit = 6;
foreach ($my_data as $node)
{   
    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $href)
    {   

        $countries[] = strip_tags(trim($href->nodeValue)); 

if($countryCount == "$countryLimit")
{
break;
}

$countryCount++


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better that way:

```
$array = $node->getElementsByTagName('a');
for($counter = 0; $counter < min(count($array), 6); ++$counter) {
    $countries[] = strip_tags($array[$counter]->nodeValue); 
}
```

A break inside a loop is kind of a bad practice I would say. This kind of loop is fast and easy to read.